# Concurrent file access in Android

Tags: java, android, concurrency, filesystems

I know that many OSes perform some sort of locking on the filesystem to prevent inconsistent views. Are there any guarantees that Java and/or Android make about thread-safety of file access? I would like to know as much about this as possible before I go ahead and write the concurrency code myself.

If I missed a similar question that was answered feel free to close this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android is built on top of Linux, so inherits Linux's filesystem semantics.  Unless you explicitly lock a file, multiple applications and threads can open it for read/write access.  Unless you actually need cross-process file synchronization, I would suggest using normal Java synchronization primitives for arbitrating access to the file.

Comment: That's pretty much what I expected.

Answer (score 5):

The normal reading/writing functionality (FileInputStream, etc) does not provide any thread-safety AFAIK. To achieve thread-safety, you need to use [FileChannel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html). This would look something like:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
FileLock lock = channel.lock();
// do some reading
lock.release();
```

I would read the [File Lock doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html), and take care with the threading!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking of using ReadWriteLock anyway so that multiple threads could read at the same time

Comment: It seems that the Filelock only works between process, but not for thread in the same android process.