# Mutual exclusion between two application

Tags: java, android, deadlock, synchronized

I want to write two Android applications which works upon a single text file .

The task for the first application (App1) -

A. Check whether the text file "abc.txt" is present at the root of the sdcard.

B. If not present, create "abc.txt" at root of sdcard.

C. Keep on writing the data into the abc.txt periodically after every 5 minutes.

The task for the second application (App2) -

A. Check whether the text file "abc.txt" is present at the root of the sdcard.

B. If present, read all of the data from the file "abc.txt" and post reading, delete it

Now I am able to read from and write to the "abc.txt" individually by the each application, but I am facing the synchronization issue. I want to make sure that if first app is writing in to the text file, second file must wait till the text file is ready to be read from. I would have used the

```
synchronized
```

keyword had it been a single app. Can someone please help me out in this scenario?

Comment: Although a bit too broad to answer, I will give you some thought: You obviuosly need an external synchronization mechanism. How about a _locking file_ - for example "abc.txt.lock"? Both apps should create such a file when doing their job and delete it afterwards. Both apps should also check for the existence of that file.

Comment: @darthvading : Please check 'Synchronizing Code (Objective 4.3)' from scjp book by Kathy Sierra..!! You will find where to use Synchronized word..!!

Comment: @darthvading  : Check this one : http://firozstar.tripod.com/_darksiderg.pdf .!!

Comment: I think you need `java.nio.channels.FileLock` - see mfrankli's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746050/concurrent-file-access-in-android

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I understood your suggestion. Still I feel that there is a chance of deadlock here too. Let's say the situation where both App1 and App2 see that "abc.txt.lock" isn't available and both try to create it OR vice versa. I know that the probability of happening this is very less, yet it may happen.

Comment: @MamataGelanee Thanks for the comment. I know 'synchronization'. But my problem is - i need synchronization within two Android applications trying to modify a single resource.

Comment: @darthvading : I think if possible you should use custom content provider (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) to save data that is shared by multiple application and Its apis are synchronized also..!!

Answer (score 0):

[`FileLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) should provide the functionality you need. You can either lock `abc.txt`, or you can lock some other file, which would be always present and would only serve as a system-wide lock for your applications.

**From the doc:**

> Multiple processes can hold shared locks on the same region of a file, but only a single process can hold an exclusive lock on a given region of a file and no other process can simultaneously hold a shared lock overlapping the exclusive lock.

You can obtain an exclusive `FileLock` on the whole file from [`FileChannel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).